# What are the main advantages, or otherwise, of developing with Vala?

Tags: vala

I read its documentation and it seems quite awesome. But I never heard of any application developed using it.

What are the main advantages and disadvantage of Vala?

Comment: Half of all new desktop applications for GNOME are developed using Vala, probably the most high-profile being Cheese (the webcam booth) and Shotwell (the photo manager). See the last section of [this page](http://live.gnome.org/Vala/Documentation) for a list of Vala success stories. Other than that, your question is really too broad to answer; perhaps you should change it to be more specific.

Answer (score 9):

(IMO)
advantages:

- No garbage collector!
- generated programs are written in C which should boost performance and require less resources than other scripting languages (python) or managed code (Mono).
- Provide easy to use API to a huge variety of useful libraries available in Linux written mostly in C.
- Provide a C#-like syntax which is very popular and by doing so attract new developers to OSS programming.
- Bring (some level of) OOP syntactic sugar into the world of C but easier to use than C++.

disadvantage:

- No garbage collector!
- Generated program should be recompiled for each architecture.
- It's a young language. Language specifications and API change constantly. Maintaining a big project might require extra attention.
- Debugging is possible but a bit tricky.
- No stable IDE and tools yet. Valide crashes a lot and vtg too.
- Language object model is based on glib/gobject which seem to be limited. Dova is being developed to explore an alternative path but will not be compatible with gobjects.

Comment: Just to clarify (for future readers), even it doesn't have a garbage collector, it has a reference-counting mechanism that can achieve the same results. While it is more efficient, it requires to follow some simple rules, which if not followed, may produce memory leaks.

Comment: +1: I would say that Debugging and unstable IDEs are the main disadvantages today (as it is a young language this will definitely change in the near future).

Comment: Working on an IDE as we speak. http://christophertimberlake.com/post/39654584097/moving-forward-with-elementary-os